# Extracting parts of a matrix based on the properties of the elements in the first column

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, indexing, extract

I have some data consisting of 2 columns and thousands of rows. The first column is time data. How do I extract the part of the data where the values in the first column are between say, 100 and 300. I can do that for a single vector x=t(find(t>=100&t<=300)), but I also want the corresponding values from the second column.

This is in Matlab, by the way.

I hope that's clear. Any ideas?

BvV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
x=t(t(:,1)>=100&t(:,1)<=300,:);
```

Comment: Note that both in the example given in the question and in this answer, you can leave out `find` and just use `x=t((t(:,1)>=100&t(:,1)<=300),:);`

Comment: ... without `find`, you will be using [logical indexing](http://www.mathworks.de/company/newsletters/articles/Matrix-Indexing-in-MATLAB/matrix.html) (look towards the end of the text).